# Clipping virtual raster generates out of memory error

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 2.16.1 on Windows to try to extract elevation data into curves that I can use to cut/build a wooden topo map.  I'm vaguely following [this guidance](http://theshamblog.com/making-a-laser-cut-topo-map-the-design-phase/), but also am changing things up a bit as needed (my data is across multiple files, etc).  I'm in really deep water here as I'm a woodworker and not a mapping person (yet!).

I've imported 6 raster layers of elevation data from the ArcGRID datasets, merged them into a Virtual Raster, and ran `Raster > Extraction > Contour` at an interval of 125.  After several minutes of chug, I get the contours.  Awesome!

My problem: Trying to save myself some data chunking time (I'm doing some smoothing and eliminating of too-small-for-wood contours), I wanted to eliminate the data and contours that are outside the boundary of the region I wanted to topo (several of the data files only overlap my region by a tiny amount).  I loaded a shapefile for the region boundary (it's a national park so finding that was easy) and used `Raster > Extraction > Clipper` to clip the Virtual Raster to the shape.  It appears to work and generate a new Clipped Raster (my name for it) in the right shape that visually matches the original data.  Problem is, when I try to run Contour on the Clipped Raster, it generates an `ERROR 1: CPLRealloc(): Out of memory allocating 416 bytes`.

As first I assumed the clipping shape was too complex, so I tried with just a square and it fails with the same error.  Seems any Clipping of the Virtual Raster drives the error.

Is there any way I can fix this or any other method to take the elevation data from multiple files, "combine it" and extract contours?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a long time ago since this question was asked, but since there's no answers yet, here's what solved the problem for me when I just had the same problem with QGIS 2.18.1. I simply tried clipping the original raster again, but this time I specified the nodata value to be a value not too far from the actual data, instead of going with the default -3.4e+38. That did the trick. I should also mention that before this I tried specifying the (default) nodata value when contouring the clipped raster, but this approach still generated the memory error.